# How can I ask a second question inside a question?

Tags: discussion, reputation, duplicate-questions, comment-replies

I have found a question which is similar to my question and has an accepted answer that doesn't satisfy me. Since I am quite new my rep is below 50, and so I am not even allowed to post a comment. Which in this case it would be fine I suppose, because I need a much more detailed answer. Obviously I'd like to avoid to create a new question to get it closed as duplicated.

Is there a way to add another question or should I go on and create a new question anyway, maybe adding a link to the old question?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

> Should I go on and create a new question anyway, maybe adding a link to the other question?

Since your question is not *identical*, that is what you should do. Place extra focus on explaining why that answer isn't good enough and what makes **your** question different.

Comment: Simply put, If it needs a different answer, it's not the same question.

Comment: You should definitely link to the old question as part of explaining why that answer isn't complete for you.

Comment: @Oded Yeah, I went on and posted my question anyway. It has been a bit popular as well, I've got some answers. And most important the one I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Glad that worked out, @Michele

Comment: What if my question is on using the accepted answer but that answer is not working for me? should I create a new question? A comment is not possible as I add some code, my data and a plot

Comment: @pacomet - if the accepted answer doesn't work for you, that's information to add to a question (so, a new, different question). Could link to the original question and the answer and explain why that doesn't work in your situation (though, assuming there are other answers - worth checking those out first as well)